# How to plot a list of lists against one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
V = [[10,20,30,40],[30,40,50,50,70]] # It may consist n lists, each list with m values
I = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6,7]] # It may consist n lists, each list with m values
for t in list(zip(V,I)):  
    plt.plot(*t)
    plt.show()
```

output is:[image: output image I got. But I want both plots to be in one figure]

[Above `V` and `I` consists of 2 lists, each list with 4 elements. I want to plot `V` and `I` in same XY figure. This V and I data is going to have 2 plots. ]

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he is just asking us to write code for him

Comment: Iterating over the `zip` of your `V` and `I` lists yields n `x` and `y` pairs which you can use to plot that particular pair.

Comment: I am just beginner to Python (3 days) and stackoverflow (4 hrs). I don't know how to write, ask for help. Sorry. I did not mean that someone will write code for me. I tried my way. But, could not get it. I have added the error output for above my code.

Comment: You need to show the code you used to try and solve this problem. You cannot plot nested lists using simply `plt.plot(V,I)` as the error message shows. In any case, @taras has given you the way to do it in their comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just zip V and I to get a list of tuples and then plot each tuple

```
for t in zip(V,I):
    plt.plot(*t)

plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image: Output plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code. I have executed the code. It is giving two different figures each consisting a plot. But, I want one figure to have two plots. Help me.

Comment: @Msquare This will not produce 2 plots unless you have an extra `plt.figure()` somewhere

Comment: @Msquare. As DavigG has mentioned, this cannot create two plots. I do get only one plot

Comment: I have not used `plt.figure()` any where in the text. First time I am drawing the plots. Here is my code which I used for executing it: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
`V = [[10,20,30,40],[30,40,50,50,70]] # It may consist n lists, each list with m values
I = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6,7]] # It may consist n lists, each list with m values
for t in list(zip(V,I)):  
    plt.plot(*t)
    plt.show()'

Comment: Now, I got it. Thanks a lot Sunitha. I understand that  I have mentioned plt.show() inside for loop which is the reason for two plots. When, it is placed outside the loop and it gives one plot, which I wanted. Thanks a lot.